# Delete bitcoin address using Pywallet

Tags: wallet

sorry for the stupid question but I can not understand that I have missed.
I'm trying to use the wallet for removing unused addresses. I get a message has been deleted successfully, but the client I still see those addresses, it seems that the removal does not work. Maybe I missed something, please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm this is very strange, make sure that on deleting your bitcoin client (Bitcoin QT etc) is closed.